# having fixed color for the plots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two data frames df1 and df2 and I am comparing one fixed column (A) from data frame 2 with different columns in data frame one (df1), but each in separate graphs e.g. A and B then A and C and so one. I want to associate a fixed color to plot A e.g. green, but when I change the column from the first data frame, the A-plot color changes.

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=df1, aes(x=t1, y=B, color='B'))+
  geom_line(data=df2, aes(x=t1, y=A, color='A')) +
  scale_colour_discrete(name="Generation")
```

This is the code I am using.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72279023/edit) with the output of `dput(df1)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df1, 20))` and the same for `df2`.

Comment: Try with `scale_color_manual` and a named vector of color, i.e. replace scale_color_discrete  by e.g. `scale_color_manual(values = c(A = "green", B = "blue", C = "red"))`

Comment: I_O in this case, it labels the graphs by the colors. I want to label them as the column name.